# Why does my images jump a few pixels when executing this parallax script?

Tags: javascript

I am not a javascript guy so I dont really understand why my code does this:

When first loading the page and scrolling, the image targeted jumps up down about 30px

```
var parallax = document.querySelectorAll(".headerphotosmall, .headerphoto"),
    speed = 0.9;

window.onscroll = function(){
    [].slice.call(parallax).forEach(function(el,i){

        var windowYOffset = window.pageYOffset,
            elBackgrounPos = "50%" + (windowYOffset * speed) + "px";

        el.style.backgroundPosition = elBackgrounPos;

    });
};
```

video showing my problem: https://i.gyazo.com/040f328ac78a5d5243e37352e19e0cf6.mp4

Comment: Is it because the scrollbar's becoming visible?

Comment: Looks like your effect doesn't start at the same offset as the initial placement, once you start scrolling, the scrolling offset is first applied and the image jumps. Either make sure that when you start out you initialise the scrolling offset to give the initial background offset or initialise your backgroundoffset according to a 0 scrolling offset.

Comment: I am not really familair with JavaScript could you give me a code example? @BeyelerStudios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @BeyelerStudios's comment explains the problem... The initial position of your images aren't related to the initial scroll position.

<sup>I don't know what is a parallax, though...</sup>

Since I don't know your CSS, I tried to auto-update the position of your parallax images when the script runs, with that `Array#forEach` loop. If you're declaring these background images later, then you need to wait the page to load.

```
var parallax, speed;
var updateBgImagePos, updateParallaxPosition;

// Converts parallax HTML collection to
// Array
parallax = [].slice.call(
    document.querySelectorAll(".headerphotosmall, .headerphoto")
);

speed = 0.9;

updateBgImagePos = function(el, i) {
    var windowYOffset = window.pageYOffset,
        elBackgrounPos = "50%" + (windowYOffset * speed) + "px";

    el.style.backgroundPosition = elBackgrounPos;
};

updateParallaxPosition = function() {
    parallax.forEach(updateBgImagePos);
};

window.onscroll = updateParallaxPosition;

// If your script is declared later than the images,
// you don't need to wait the page to load  to
// get/modify them.
updateParallaxPosition();
```